# email form not carrying email to php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, email

I have an email input field and a submit button, which when pressed I want a text field to change telling the user that they are subscribed. For some reason the email field is not relaying to the php file what email was typed in.  However I know the php is being executed  because it just give me an subscription error every time.  There was another question like this asked on here but the solution did not work.

I think it is an issue with the use of `<form>` and `<button>` in combination but I do not know the proper way to execute this, any ideas?

The html:

```
   <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
      <title>Community Sound</title>
    </head>   
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({url: "phEmail.php", success: function(result){
                $("#div1").html(result);
            }});
        });
    });
    </script>  
    <body>
      <!--  Subscription  -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="no-result vertical-align-outer">
          <div class="vertical-align">
            <form method="post" >
              <input name="email" class="email glowing-border" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address ...">
              <button type="button" onclick="return getData()" class="emailbtn">Subscribe</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>     
         <div id="div1">Not Subscribed</div>
</body>
</head>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$to = "garvernr@mail.uc.edu";
$from = "newsubscription@samplepackgenerator.com";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$subject = "New subscription";
$body = "New user subscription: " . $_POST['email'];
if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
{ 
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from))
    {
        echo 'You have been added to our mailing list!';
    }
    else
    {
       echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';
    }
}
else
{
   echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't provide a data parameter to the Ajax call

Comment: Where is getData() function you call from first onClick handler?

Comment: @bksi that was the solution this other guy had that i tried to copy, my bad

Answer (score 1):

You can either send the form data via a form post to another page OR you can issue an ajax call. Currently you are trying something inbetween and have two `onClick` handlers, one in the control itself `onclick="return getData()"` and one added via jQuery.

The first one is missing completely and the second one from above (jQuery AJAX) doesn't send any data.

Change it that way:

```
....
 <button type="button" id="sendbutton"  class="emailbtn">Subscribe</button>
....
```

And your ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendbutton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                 url: "phEmail.php", 
                 data: { "email": $('#sendbutton').val() },
                success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
```

When your familiar with that, you may consider serializing the entire form in one go, which would be more generic. Have a look at the jQuery docs for that

Comment: wow this is so helpful, thank you so much. Yes I will definitely be looking into that.  It seems like there is always a more clever way that can make your html work a little bit better lol

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form doesn't send any data.

You need to modify your ajax call and add the data arrtibute.

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       url: "phEmail.php",
       data:{email: $("input.email").value},
       success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i entered the data line in however I still get the same error because the email is not there :/

Comment: Try $("input.email").val()